# Hide "Enhanced Rich Text" field on DispForm if it is empty

Tags: jquery, custom-form, display-form, hide-elements, multiple-lines-of-text

I'm working on the customization of the DispForm and I need to check if the "Enhanced Rich Text" field is empty -> hide, if not empty -> show (column in the DispForm).

I don't have a problem with hiding the field, but I'm struggling with IF statement(to check if the enhanced rich text field is empty or not). Below IF statement works perfectly for the NewForm and the EditForm, but not for DispForm.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".ms-rtestate-field[id^='EnhancedRichTextField']")[0].innerHTML==""){
        $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('EnhancedRichTextField')").parent().hide();
    }else{
        $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('EnhancedRichTextField')").parent().show();
    }
    $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('HideCalculatedField1')").parent().hide();
    $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('HideCalculatedField2')").parent().hide();
    $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('HideCalculatedField3')").parent().hide();
    $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('HideCalculatedField4')").parent().hide();

});
```

Any idea? 
I also tried: `if($("td.ms-formbody[id^='SPFieldNote']").val()=="")`

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you inspect the enhanced rich text box by clicking on it and selecting inspect element and share the screenshot of the html of that rich text?

Comment: if field is empty html looks like this: _<tr><td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_EnhancedRichTextField"></a>EnhancedRichTextField</h3></td> <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote"> <!-- FieldName="EnhancedRichTextField" FieldInternalName="EnhancedRichTextField" FieldType="SPFieldNote" --> </td> </tr>_

Comment: if field is NOT empty: _<tr><td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_EnhancedRichTextField"></a>EnhancedRichTextField</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="EnhancedRichTextField"
    FieldInternalName="EnhancedRichTextField"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   <div class="ms-rtestate-field"><div dir=""><div class="ExternalClass59318174FD784FF7A23ED3CDF3460E4E">dolorem ipsum<br><p>​</p></div></div></div></td></tr>_

Comment: This is not the complete html of the rich text field. The field should be an editable div element.

Comment: There should be a div ending with "$TextField_inplacerte"

Comment: Yes you are right..

Comment: Below if statement works perfectly for EditForm and NewForm, but not for DispForm imho because of the missing div which contains 'ms-rtestate-write'. _if($(".ms-rtestate-write[id^='EnhancedRichTextField]")[0].innerHTML=="<p>​</p>")_. And if I use _if($("td.ms-formbody[id^='SPFieldNote']").val()==""){_ the field is hidden, but for both cases empty/notempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF statement -> check if Enhanced Rich Text field on DispForm is empty -> hide, else -> show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var textField =  $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("EnhancedRichTextField")').siblings(".ms-formbody").text().trim();  
  if(textField.length==0){
        $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('EnhancedRichTextField')").parent().hide();
  }else{
        $("td.ms-formlabel:contains('EnhancedRichTextField')").parent().show();
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript solution to hide the td.

```
document.querySelectorAll('td[id=SPFieldNote]').forEach(function(element){
    var fieldTitleElement = element.previousElementSibling;
    if(fieldTitleElement.innerText.indexOf("EnhancedRichTextField") > -1){
        if(!element.innerText.trim()){
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to hide the whole row (), then you just need to add .parrent to the element while hiding (shown below).

```
document.querySelectorAll('td[id=SPFieldNote]').forEach(function(element){
    var fieldTitleElement = element.previousElementSibling;
    if(fieldTitleElement.innerText.indexOf("EnhancedRichTextField") > -1){
        if(!element.innerText.trim()){
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Harshal! It didn't work for my case...but you shown me the right direction -> I've found the solution.